# Mellin Transform of $h(x-a)$

Tags: integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The question is from Integral Transform For Engineers By Andrews and Shivamoggi.

Evaluate the Mellin transform of the given function. 
When possible, use known integral results from previous chapters.

$1.f(x)=h(a-x)$ $a>0$

I started as $M${$h(x-a),s$}=$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}h(x-a)dx=\int_{a}^{\infty}x^{s-1}dx=\frac{x^s}{s}\Big|_a^\infty $$

But the resultant answer will be  infinity.I know this is not correct.Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Infinity if $s>0$. How about $s<0$ and $s=0$?

Comment: $s$ is a complex number,so we cannot say about it being positive or negative.I think  using $s=a+ib$ i can say $M${$h(x-a),s$}$=\frac{-a^s}{s} $ provided $re(s)<0$

Comment: Please use a different symbol than $a$ to distinguish it from the $a$ you already have. Otherwise I believe you have your answer.